# for loop over every nth element in R

Tags: r

I have a some files in a folder and I could list them using dir()

```
epochs <- dir(path = paste0(getwd(), "/", "model"))
# sort epochs in increasing order
epochs <- mixedsort(epochs)

epochs
  [1] "epoch 0"   "epoch 1"   "epoch 2"   "epoch 3"   "epoch 4"   "epoch 5"   "epoch 6"   "epoch 7"   "epoch 8"   "epoch 9"   "epoch 10" 
 [12] "epoch 11"  "epoch 12"  "epoch 13"  "epoch 14"  "epoch 15"  "epoch 16"  "epoch 17"  "epoch 18"  "epoch 19"  "epoch 20"  "epoch 21" 
 [23] "epoch 22"  "epoch 23"  "epoch 24"  "epoch 25"  "epoch 26"  "epoch 27"  "epoch 28"  "epoch 29"  "epoch 30"
```

Is there a way to iterate over every nth element (e.g. 0, 2, 4, ...) of epochs. I wish to continue to iterate over elements of epochs, not the indices which would have made it fairly easy (seq_along, seq)

```
for (epoch in epochs)
{
  print(epoch)
}
```

I want to loop in increasing order but the sequence is different. How can I correct it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the subset of `epochs` you want to loop over as the vector in the `for` statement:

```
subset_of_epochs <- epochs[seq(from=1, to=N, by=2)] #or whichever ones you want

for (epoch in subset_of_epochs) {
   ... 
}
```